# Text blinking in Android, with most concise Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-view

I need to make some text (currently in a `TextView`) blink for a few seconds. There's several answers on [how to do it in java here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11991435/4433326), but since Kotlin has some syntax/language features that java doesn't, I'm asking what is the most concise way you found to make text blink on Android using Kotlin.

While I'm aiming at making a fading/smooth blink, I'm open to approaches that would make a non smooth blink too.

Note that I'm also looking at lightweight code performance wise.

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For a bit of fun, you can define an extension function:

```
fun View.blink(
    times: Int = Animation.INFINITE,
    duration: Long = 50L,
    offset: Long = 20L,
    minAlpha: Float = 0.0f,
    maxAlpha: Float = 1.0f,
    repeatMode: Int = Animation.REVERSE
) {
    startAnimation(AlphaAnimation(minAlpha, maxAlpha).also {
        it.duration = duration
        it.startOffset = offset
        it.repeatMode = repeatMode
        it.repeatCount = times
    })
}
```

And use it like so (using the example in the question you linked):

```
myText.blink(3)  // Blink 3 times
yourText.blink()  // Just keep blinking
```

Obviously you can change the parameters to suit your use case.

To stop the animation if needed, call `clearAnimation()` on the blinking view (`yourText` for the example above).

Comment: Nice, simple and concise!

Comment: Hey I know this is an old question but, how do I blink the text inside a checkbox?